# Accessing underlying DbDataReader in Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, teradata, dapper

I am querying a Teradata database using Dapper with no issues. However, I'd like now to retrieve the records count before fetching rows. TdDataReader exposes a RecordsReturned property with this information. How can I retrieve this data while using Dapper to map query results?

Comment: `var count = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableName");` ?

Comment: @Selvin: There's no need for a count query as Teradata returns the number of rows in a result  in the *RecordsReturned* property set *before* returning the data.

Comment: @dnoeth then what is this question about?

Comment: Dapper has extension methods directly on `IDataReader` (`Parse`, `GetRowParser`), so just get a data reader in the usual way (`Command.ExecuteReader` or Dapper's own `IDbConnection.ExecuteReader` extensions) and do whatever you like with it before processing the results.

Comment: @Selvin: The question is how to get the value in the *RecordsReturned* property :-) I don't know about Dapper, but Jeroen hoppefully answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using `IDbConnection.ExecuteReader` and `IDataReader.Parse` according to @Jeroen comment.

```
var reader = connection.ExecuteReader(...);
var dataReader = ((IWrappedDataReader)reader).Reader;
var records = ((TdDataReader)dataReader).RecordsReturned;
var data = reader.Parse<T>();
```